# Laravel horizon supervisor priority

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

I am working in kubernetes and having 2 pods:

- cpu_encoder
- gpu_encoder (a pod with a GPU mounted)

both are running `php artisan horizon` with the same settings

What I'd like to do is to give priority to the encoder with a mounted GPU until it runs out of processes, than the cpu encoder takes up from there.

I can dispatch jobs on one or multiple queues/connections etc, I have no restrictions of any kind regarding laravel horizon setup.

As soon as the GPU encoder has some free processes, it takes priority back again.

Is this even possible with laravel horizon ?

EDIT: actually I am running a similar setup with rabbitMQ, and the GPU consumer can get higher priority with the `--args=x-priority=10` parameter, is there something similar to do with horizon ?